# Devexpress delete a row

Tags: grid, devexpress, rows

Using DevExpress's Grid, what the easiest way to implement a delete of a selection of rows from the UI only. The desired behavior is for the user to multi-select rows then press DEL.

I have enabled editing and multi-select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Devexpress Support Center and assuming that you are referring to a Windows Form Grid:

> To delete multiple selected rows use
>   the GridView.DeleteSelectedRows
>   method. If you need to conditionally
>   protect some rows from deletion,
>   iterate through the
>   GridView.SelectedRows array, and
>   unselect certain rows using the
>   GridView.UnselectRow method.

[How to delete the multiple rows in the grid?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ59031.aspx?searchtext=delete+multiple+rows&p=T4|P1|56)

You also need to handle the key down event of the grid if you want to delete the selected rows on a key press.

If it's not Windows Forms you can search their Support Center by product. From my experience the technical support there is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

The method that I use generally is,

```
GridView.DeleteRow(GridView.FocusedRowHandle)
```

It works well.